# Press ENTER in a program via .bat file

Tags: windows, batch, batch-file

I want to start WhatsApp and send message with a .bat file. I will run this .bat file via another program. I haven't used a .bat file before so I don't know anything about it. I just wrote this :

```
start chrome "https://wa.me/+905061234567?text=nbr".
```

This starts WhatsApp but couldn't send message because it needs pressing ENTER. Can you help me please? thanks.

Comment: batch can't do that. You need (the help of) another language.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Which language I need? ie Visual Basic, C, Python..?

Comment: Sorry, this is out of my range of knowledge. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43579406/sendkey-to-specific-application) may be helpful.

Comment: There are projects to do so, e.g. https://dev.to/mayronceccon/sending-whatsapp-messages-with-command-line-370p

Comment: Thanks Stephan. That helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```bat
<!-- ::

@echo off & start "" /b chrome "https://wa.me/+905061234567?text=nbr"
"%__AppDir__%WScript.exe" "%~dpnx0?.wsf" && goto :EOF || rem :: -->

<job><script language="vbscript">Set objShell=WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.AppActivate "chrome.exe" : WScript.Sleep 1000 
For x = 1 To 8
   WScript.Sleep 200 : objShell.SendKeys "{TAB}" 
Next
WScript.Sleep 1000 : objShell.SendKeys "Hey, how are you?~" : WScript.Sleep 1000 : objShell.SendKeys "~" </script></job>
```

---

**1.** You may need to add VBS in your bat file...

**2.** Some adjustments for navigation via keys may be necessary to adjust when in use for App/Web interfaces

**3.** You may also need to adjust the timeout according to the interface in use

---

- For the same in **[powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell)**:

```bat
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell

Start-Process "chrome.exe" "https://wa.me/+905061234567?text=" 

sleep -m 600 ; $wshell.AppActivate('Share on WhatsApp') ; Start-Sleep -m 200
1..8 | % {; sleep -m 300 ; [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("{TAB}")}

[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait('~') ; sleep -m 500
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait('Hey, how are you?~')
```

---

- Some further reading **[vbs](/questions/tagged/vbs)/[cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd)/[bat](/questions/tagged/bat)**:

  - **[Hybrid VBS/Bat Files](https://ss64.com/vb/syntax-hybrid.html)**
  - **[WSF - Windows Script File](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Script_File)**
  - **[SendKeys Method in VBScript](https://ss64.com/vb/sendkeys.html)**
  - **[Execute Hybrid Bat/Scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9074476/is-it-possible-to-embed-and-execute-vbscript-within-a-batch-file-without-using-a)**

---

- Some further reading **[ps1](/questions/tagged/ps1)**

  - **[Get-Content](https://ss64.com/ps/get-content.html)**
  - **[start-process](https://ss64.com/ps/start-process.html)**
  - **[Start-Sleep](https://ss64.com/ps/start-sleep.html)**
  - **[Get-Clipboard](https://ss64.com/ps/set-clipboard.html)**
  - **[SendKeys Method](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-xp/aa202943(v=office.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)**